# Query the result of a query in the same cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I don't know how else to put it of phrase it, I am really stumped here. I will put what I have down below and hopefully, someone will understand what I am getting at.

```
=QUERY(Sheet3!A:B,"select B where A =QUERY(Sheet2!B:D,"select D where B = '"&A2&"'",0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Formulas

A Google Sheets formulas start with `=` or `+`. A formula can't be inside of another formula. In other words, the `=` could be used as operator inside of a formula only when comparing two values, i.e. `=IF(A1=B1,"Success!","Failure")`

QUERY

The second argument of QUERY is a optional text value. You could use the functions and operators to build this text value, but it should be a single (escalar ) value, so you could use QUERY inside  QUERY only if the first one helps you to build this text value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **D** column is text then it would be like this:

```
=QUERY(Sheet3!A:B, "select B where A = '"&
 QUERY(Sheet2!B:D, "select D where B = '"&A2&"' limit 1", 0)&"'", 0)
```